# Http response through service sends content (mime) type in text/html but not application/json

Tags: java, http, basecamp

My application using `Oauth` for `basecam` api. I am trying to get `Httpresponse` into `json` format but it revert into plain html (text/html) content-type. so there is no method to parse HTML content and get the token from `basecamp`. This is not homework but a small R&D to quick start `Oauth` protocol. as am new to `oauth`.

```
//HERE -> final String JSON_CONTENT = "application/json"
String contentType = OAuthConstants.JSON_CONTENT;

    if (response.getEntity().getContentType() != null) {
        contentType = response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue();
        //BELOW -> getting contentType is in "text/html; utf-8
        System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue()); //text/html; charset=utf-8
    }

    if (contentType.contains(OAuthConstants.JSON_CONTENT)) {
        return handleJsonResponse(response);
    } else 
        if (contentType.contains(OAuthConstants.URL_ENCODED_CONTENT)) {
          return handleURLEncodedResponse(response);
        } else 
            if (contentType.contains(OAuthConstants.XML_CONTENT)) {
              return handleXMLResponse(response);
            }   
            else {
                // Unsupported Content type
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Cannot handle "
                                + contentType
                                + " content type. Supported content types include JSON, XML and URLEncoded");
            }
```

So above lines explain very well that control won't come is json, xml or `url_encoded` if-else. Si either i need to parse text/html into json or xml response or i have to create another method name `handleHtmlResponse()`. what way it would be continent to get `contentType`.

Comment: text/html is also the content type of an error response. Are you sure, you are not receiving an error message?

Comment: I am getting my own runtime exception says, Cannot handle text/html; charset=utf-8 content type. Supported content types include JSON, XML and URLEncoded

Comment: What is the HTTP status of the web response? Have you dumped the response body (the received html) or checked the network traffic?

Comment: I am getting the error but not HTTP status. Cannot handle text/html;charset=UTF-8 content type. 
I am giving:
 #--------OAuth2.0 Client Configuration---------
#scope=
grant_type=password
username={email}
password={password}
client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrDiCL6SPsuE7cn7y7.cYzz9O5cCRFP1cbF7GRRAA_ntB.G1EzAbM0ftLqhYF_lEDxVhHTf6
client_secret={some value here}
#access_token=
#refresh_token=
authentication_server_url=https://login.salesforce.com
#resource_server_url=https://ap2.salesforce.com/02u28000000QfzC

Answer (score 0):

After the response is set with all the data(header, body ...), commit it by calling [ServletResponse#flushBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#flushBuffer).

Comment: Please find the link i just copy pasted code from github.
[link] https://github.com/danielsz/android-oauth2-client/blob/master/src/org/sdf/danielsz/OAuthUtils.java